# Cannot run Liberty server locally - error: Plug-in "com.ibm.ws.st.core" was unable to instantiate class WebSphereLaunchConfigurationDelegate

Tags: eclipse, server, websphere-liberty

Trying to set up Liberty Server for running wlp locally.  I have done this before, but now get an error:
Plug-in "com.ibm.ws.st.core" was unable to instantiate class "com.ibm.ws.st.core.internal.launch.WebSphereLaunchConfigurationDelegate".
org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener

I don't see anything regarding this to dig into it.  Anyone have experience with this?  On the ibm websphere site, I get web site errors when trying to submit the error to IBM support

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which version of Java is running it? Heck, which version of the Liberty server and its plug-ins?

Comment: Sorry for providing too few details.  I had tried several versions of Eclipse and everything else.  Eclipse 2022-03 was one, but finally 2021-09.  I was using openJDK11 and switched to Java 8.  IBM Liberty Developer Tools 21.0.0.9 is what I settled on.  Liberty web profile 22.0.0.6 was the most recent I tried.  I did find a workaround (solution?) I will enter next

Answer (score 0):

- Eclipse 2021-09
- Java 8
- IBM Liberty Developer Tools 21.0.0.9
- Liberty web profile 22.0.0.6

When installing the Developer tools, I got an "Install Remediation Page".  When I was getting the error, I had selected, "Keep my installation the same and modify the items being installed to be compatible".  [image: remediation page - modify install]
The final and successful attempt, I selected "Update my installation t obe compatible with the items being installed" [image: update install]